# C# getting the results of two differently names tables that are identical in their structure into one object

Tags: c#, sql

For example I have a object `var newRegionalReportRecord = new RegionalReportRecord();` now I am using SQL to fill this object with data from two tables which are identical in structure. At the momenet I am using a UNION like so:

```
            sql.Append("  ID ");
            sql.Append(", mercid ");
            sql.Append(", mercname ");
            sql.Append(", termid ");
            sql.Append(", PAN ");
            sql.Append(", edcbatch ");
            sql.Append(", transeq ");
            sql.Append(", tranauth ");
            sql.Append(", trandt ");
            sql.Append(", trantm ");
            sql.Append(", trandbcr ");
            sql.Append(", tranamt ");
           
            sql.Append("From ");
            sql.Append(applicationSettings.TablePOSSettlementRecords);
            sql.Append(" ");
            sql.Append("UNION ");

            sql.Append("Select ");
            sql.Append("  ID ");
            sql.Append(", mercid ");
            sql.Append(", mercname ");
            sql.Append(", termid ");
            sql.Append(", PAN ");
            sql.Append(", edcbatch ");
            sql.Append(", transeq ");
            sql.Append(", tranauth ");
            sql.Append(", trandt ");
            sql.Append(", trantm ");

            sql.Append("From ");
            sql.Append("applicationSettings.TablePOSSettlementRecords_investigations");
```

Now my question is are there other methods that are more elegant and on the C# side of doing this rather than doing it in sql?

Comment: Why are you generating the SQL like that? It makes it _super_ hard to read.

Comment: But, at a high level, your approach looks fine (although you may want to consider UNION ALL rather than UNION). _I am surprised it lets you do a union when there are different numbers of columns in the two queries to be honest_.

Comment: @mjwills ah there are actually the same I just cut off a few

Comment: Perhaps hide the query in a View or SP. Its not in C# as your question asked though.

Comment: I'd strongly recommend you use a verbatim string prefixed with `@`, you can embed newlines which makes it easier to read, and makes it less likely you'll try SQL injection

Comment: How can you fill the single object with data from two tables?